# Cannot get BitRate_Mode from mediainfo CLI

Tags: mediainfo

Following is my bat file:

```
@echo off
mediainfo --Inform=file://template.txt "in.mp4" >info.txt
```

Following is my template.txt

```
General;File is: %FileName%\r\n 
Video;\r\nFormat: %Format%\r\nCodecID: %CodecID%\r\nResolution: %Width%x%Height%\r\nDAR: %DisplayAspectRatio/String% or %DisplayAspectRatio%\r\nPAR: %PixelAspectRatio%\r\nFrameMode: %FrameRate_Mode%\r\nVideoBitrateMode: %BitRate_Mode%\r\nScanType: %ScanType%

Audio;\r\nAudioCodec: %Format%\r\nAudioBitrateMode: %BitRate_Mode%
```

Following is the output (in info.txt)

```
File is: in

Format: AVC
CodecID: avc1
Resolution: 1280x720
DAR: 16:9 or 1.778
PAR: 1.000
FrameMode: VFR
VideoBitrateMode: 
ScanType: Progressive
AudioCodec: AAC
AudioBitrateMode: VBR
```

No matter what I do I can't get MediaInfo to give BitRate_Mode for any given file?
Following is the CLI help document for mediainfo:
[Help doc](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aAHOIFbYmwAwJ%3amy-coder-gui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/MyCoderGui/MyCoderGui/bin/Debug/tools/MediaInfo/Contrib/CLI_Help.doc%20video%20bitratemode%20mediainfo&hl=en&gl=pk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESiBhbyqX9Gkt9qw8TyFe7fjoCwfdbxtpgcfU70R9ROU4gH8-DyfGqr4Lw20I-b0RMncV_OGHByfbUkahPBLPrdgYPmgYojw8EpbIaa-G5xwW73V_HUqBaLsPBcAhyDmI7qAKTr0&sig=AHIEtbSI9JhD4TeRNVPD6zHFUusCSBYJmg)

Answer (score 3):

I did exhaustive tests and I have found that most of the time mediainfo doesn't return the %BitRate_Mode% on video tracks, but it does return the %BitRate_Maximum% and if you compare it to the %BitRate% and it is different, it is a VBR video, here is my template:

```
General;Name.........: %FileName%.%FileExtension%\r\nSize.........: %FileSize/String%\r\nDuration.....: %Duration/String3%\r\n
Video;Resolution...: %Width%x%Height%\r\nCodec........: %Codec/String% %Format_Profile%\r\nBitrate......: %BitRate/String%\r\nMax Bitrate..: %BitRate_Maximum/String%\r\nFramerate....: %FrameRate% fps\r\nAspect Ratio.: %DisplayAspectRatio/String%\r\n
Audio;Audio........: %Language/String% %BitRate/String% %BitRate_Mode% %Channel(s)% chnls %Codec/String%\r\n
Text;%Language/String%
Text_Begin;Subs.........: 
Text_Middle;, 
Text_End;.\r\n
```

It will retirn something like this:

```
Name.........: My Video.m4v
Size.........: 8.23 GiB
Duration.....: 02:20:02.880
Resolution...: 1920x800
Codec........: AVC High@L3.0
Bitrate......: 7 504 Kbps
Max Bitrate..: 27.1 Mbps
Framerate....: 23.976 fps
Aspect Ratio.: 2.40:1
Audio........: English 448 Kbps CBR 6 chnls AC3
Audio........: Spanish 448 Kbps CBR 6 chnls AC3
Subs.........: English, Spanish.
```

Comment: I am not sure that works too well.  I am using DLL not CLI, but I cant get `BitRate_Mode/String` either.  Your idea sounded neat but MOST of the BitRate variants (Min, Max, Nominal) can (will) return an empty string.  So comparing a number to "" will lead you to conclude VBR perhaps wrongly.  I might not expect to see a MIN and MAX in a CBR stream, so it might be safer to conclude CBR only when they are present and the same.  I think that is the default logic in MediaTab.